# Pause and resume setinterval using simple javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Im using simple javascript function for Timer. I need to resume and pause the timer. Im not familiar with javascript so couldn't get perfect solution for this. So please help me to do this.

My javascript function for timer is

```
function start_time(){
var hrs = $('#hrs').val();
var min = $('#mins').val();
var sec = $('#sec').val();
var value = "00:00";
if (typeof $.cookie("hors") !== 'undefined') {
    var hrs = $.cookie("hors");
    var min = $.cookie("mins");
    var sec = $.cookie("seco");
}
if ($('#timer').length) {
    var runningtime = setInterval(function(){
        document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = pad2(hrs)+" : "+pad2(min)+" : "+pad2(sec);
        if (sec < 00) {
            hrs--;
            sec = 60;
            min = 60;
        }
        sec--;
        if(sec == 00){
            min--;
            sec = 60;
            if(min == 00){
               hrs--; 
               min = 60
            }
        }
        var strTime=$('#timer').text();
        arr = strTime.split(':');
        hour = parseInt(arr[0]);
        mins = parseInt(arr[1]);
        seco = parseInt(arr[2]);
        $.cookie("hors", hour); 
        $.cookie("mins", mins); 
        $.cookie("seco", seco);
        if (hrs < 0){
            clearInterval(runningtime);
            document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = "Time Up";
            $('.cover').css('display', 'block');
            $.removeCookie("hors");
            $.removeCookie("mins");
            $.removeCookie("seco");
        }
    },1000);
 }
 function pad2(number) {
     return (number.length < 2 ? '0' : '') + number
 }
```

And my HTML to render timer is

```
<input type="hidden" name="" value="01" id="hrs">
<input type="hidden" name="" value="20" id="mins">
<input type="hidden" name="" value="30" id="sec">
<div id="timer"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The setInterval function in JavaScript will call the provided function at the time every interval passes. Your code is more complex than necessary. I would recommend using a single variable to store the progress of the timer:

```
// A Javascript Class example
var Timer = function() {
// SCOPE THE CLASS
var self = this;

// PROPERTIES
self.timer;
self.currentTime;

// Start Timer
self.startTimer = function() {
   // Initialize the value of currentTime if not already set
   if (self.currentValue == -1) {
       // Get this value from a form, I notice that you are using multiple fields...you can add these values together after collecting them and multiply them to the value of a second
       currentTime = $('#timer').val();
   }
   // Start the interval, we have to save a reference to the interval in a class variable to stop the interval later
   self.timer = setInterval(function() {
       // Update your variable on every call
       // A timer would start with the number of seconds and count down
       // Your interval is a second, so every second, subtract a second
       self.currentTime--;
       // Update the value of the form with ID 'timer'
       $('#timer').val(self.currentTime);

       // Check if the timer has run out
       if (currentTime <= 0) {
           // Execute the anything you want to do when the time runs out (sound/display message?)
           self.timerExpired();
       }
   }, 1000);
};

self.stopTimer = function() {
   // An Interval can be stopped using the clearInterval() function
   clearInterval(self.timer);
   // Our class-wide variable self.currentTime will have the last value at the last interval executed
}

self.timerExpired = function() {
   // Do what you need to when the time expires
};

};
```